# Parsing a JSON String which was originally encoded using Jackson with the Jackson parser throws an IOExeption

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I made a fairly basic Java object which holds three variables; a String, a String[] and a String[][]. This encoded into a JSON object perfectly fine using Jackson and I was able to print it. However trying to parse this String using Jackson will not give me the object back, it simply throws an IOException.

The code below can be used to duplicate my issue.

Object:

```
public class CityJSON {

    String[] currentCityList;
    String brokenCity;
    String[][] cityCosts;

    CityJSON(String[] ccl, String bc, String[][] cc){
        currentCityList = ccl;
        brokenCity = bc;
        cityCosts = cc;
    }

    public String[] getCurrentCityList() {
        return currentCityList;
    }

    public void setCurrentCityList(String[] currentCityList) {
        this.currentCityList = currentCityList;
    }

    public String getBrokenCity() {
        return brokenCity;
    }

    public void setBrokenCity(String brokenCity) {
        this.brokenCity = brokenCity;
    }

    public String[][] getCityCosts() {
        return cityCosts;
    }

    public void setCityCosts(String[][] cityCosts) {
        this.cityCosts = cityCosts;
    }

}
```

Encoder and Parser:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String args[]){


        String[] cities = {"A city", "Another city"};
        String[] one = {"cost1", "cost2"};
        String[] two = {"cost3", "cost4"};
        String[][] twod = new String[2][2];
        twod[0] = one;
        twod[1] = two;
        CityJSON json = new CityJSON(cities, "myCity", twod);


        String gen = "";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            gen = mapper.writeValueAsString(json);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        System.out.println(gen);


        try {
            CityJSON ob = new ObjectMapper().readValue(gen, CityJSON.class);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("FAILED");
        }

    }
}
```

The catch statement will be triggered causing "FAILED" to be printed.

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the IOException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IOException states:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class CityJSON]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
>    at [Source: {"currentCityList":["A city","Another city"],"brokenCity":"myCity","cityCosts":[["cost1","cost2"],["cost3","cost4"]]}; line: 1, column: 2]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)

So create a no-arg constructor, or annotate the existing constructor with `@JsonCreator` and annotate the args to that constructor with `@JsonProperty("propertyName")` - eg

```
@JsonCreator
CityJSON(
    @JsonProperty("currentCityList") String[] ccl,
    @JsonProperty("brokenCity") String bc,
    @JsonProperty("cityCosts")String[][] cc
){
    currentCityList = ccl;
    brokenCity = bc;
    cityCosts = cc;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. In the environment I have been developing in, the full details of exceptions were not, by default, viewable and thus I missed this valuable information. I have managed to get ti working in the way I want by adding an empty constructor.